# REST POST request not working on java but works on REST client

Tags: java, c#, android, rest, post

Good morning!

I've created a REST service with C# and I'm trying to send a post request from android-studio to the URL. My URL has two methods currently, GET and POST. The GET method works fine, I'm able to consume from android without any problem. But when it comes to the POST request I'm not able to use it from android.

I've tested the POST method using the REST client chrome add-on and it looks like the request works fine, I'm able to reach the method and execute whatever the code needs to execute. Below the evidence:

Request data:

[image: Request data]

Request response:

[image: Request response]

Below the C# api:

```
[RoutePrefix("api/leads")]
    public class LeadsController : ApiController
    {
        // GET: api/Leads/5
        public List<Lead> Get(string matricula, int tipo)
        {
            List<Lead> leads = new List<Lead>();

            //Fills the list

            return leads;
        }

        [HttpPost]
        // POST: api/Leads
        public bool Post(int id, string usuario, string latitude, string longitude)
        {
            //Do stuff

            return true;
        }
}
```

And last, but not least, the java code that I'm using to the POST request:

```
@Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
        URL url = null;
        try {
            String newUrl = getNewUrl();

            StringBuilder postData = new StringBuilder();

            for (Map.Entry<String,Object> param : params.entrySet()) {
                if (postData.length() != 0) postData.append('&');
                postData.append(URLEncoder.encode(param.getKey(), "UTF-8"));
                postData.append('=');
                postData.append(URLEncoder.encode(String.valueOf(param.getValue()), "UTF-8"));
            }

            url = new URL(newUrl);

            byte[] postDataBytes = postData.toString().getBytes("UTF-8");

            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            conn.setDoOutput(true);
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", String.valueOf(postDataBytes.length));


            conn.getOutputStream().write(postDataBytes);

            int responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
            if(responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK){
                server_response = readStream(conn.getInputStream());
            }

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            listener.onPostResponse(false, e.getMessage(), this.tipoAcesso);
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            listener.onPostResponse(false, e.getMessage(), this.tipoAcesso);
        } catch (ProtocolException e) {
            listener.onPostResponse(false, e.getMessage(), this.tipoAcesso);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            listener.onPostResponse(false, e.getMessage(), this.tipoAcesso);
        }
        return null;
    }
```

The URL that the method getNewUrl() return is: "https://cliente.teleatlantic.com.br/CheckinLeads/api/Leads/".

The parameters are: "usuario=FERNANDOCHAVES&latitude=-46.6903502&longitude=-46.6903502&id=265857"

I've looked tirelessly all over the internet (this forum included) for a way of fixing my problem with POST requests. But none of the solutions that I've found solved my problem.

What I've tried so far:
1.Append "?" before parameters sent in the POST request.
2.Append "/CheckinLeads/api/Leads?" before the parameters.
3.Change the code to use HttpClient instead of HttpURLConnection.
4.Change content data to "text/json".
5. Many "ready to use" functions with HttpURLConnection and HttpClient.

I'm new to java/android and any help would be appreciated.
I'm using 4.4 Android KitKat SDK Version 24.
Thanks for the attention! Best regards.

**-----EDIT-----**
The code doesn't crash. But when I check the HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode of the request it shows me a 404. But the URL and parameters that I sent are the same used to test within the REST client.

Comment: `I'm not able to use it from android` how exactly? what exactly is wrong? Does it crash? return wrong result? return error?...

Comment: It doesn't crash, just doesn't reach the server. If I check for the HttpUrlConnection.getResponseCode(); it shows me a 404. But the request URL and parameters are right. I can't see what I'm missing.

Comment: can you call the below static url once from android
https://cliente.teleatlantic.com.br/CheckinLeads/api/Leads?usuario=FERNANDOCHAVES&latitude=-46.6903502&longitude=-46.6903502&id=265857

Content-Type= "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"

Comment: @ChintanUdeshi sorry, but I didn't get it. Are you saying to try setting the content-type to "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"? I've already tried this property and still getting 404 response.

Comment: have you tried with this static url 
https://cliente.teleatlantic.com.br/CheckinLeads/api/Leads?usuario=FERNANDOCHAVES&latitude=-46.6903502&longitude=-46.6903502&id=265857?

Comment: @ChintanUdeshi tried now, get the following error: `java.net.MalformedURLException: Protocol not found: cliente.teleatlantic.com.br/CheckinLeads/api/Leads/` when setting a `new URL();`

Comment: seems to me https is not added to url is it so?

Comment: @ChintanUdeshi yes, I've tried without https this time as you said. But the URL has always been `https://cliente.teleatlantic.com.br/CheckinLeads/api/Leads/`. The method getNewUrl returns a String constant with the URL: `public static final String urlLeads = "https://cliente.teleatlantic.com.br/CheckinLeads/api/Leads/";`

Comment: can you change the api code 
public class test
    { 
        public int id {get;set;}
        public string usuario {get;set;}
        public string latitude {get;set;}
        public string longitude { get; set; }
    }

[HttpPost]
        // POST: api/Leads
        public bool Post(test objTest)
        {
            //Do stuff

            return true;
        }

Comment: @ChintanUdeshi It worked! Thanks, thanks a lot! Please post as an answer so I can mark as solved! But, why does this happens? Why as primitive types I wasn't able to call the API and when I changed to an object it worked?

Comment: @Abner yes i have posted this as answer
lets discuss in chat let me know once you are available

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135258/discussion-between-abner-and-chintan-udeshi).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Change the api code 

public class test { 
public int id {get;set;} 
public string usuario {get;set;} 
public string latitude {get;set;} 
public string longitude { get; set; } 
} 

[HttpPost] 
// POST: api/Leads 
public bool Post(test objTest) 
{ 
//Do stuff return true; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are posting data to server but your parameters are not in JSON format so you need to encode parameters using  `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

Try:

```
conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
```

And have a look at [this](http://homakov.blogspot.se/2012/06/x-www-form-urlencoded-vs-json-pros-and.html)

Comment: thanks for your reply. I've tried setting this property before and it just doesn't work. Still getting 404 as the response to the request.